# Contractor/Vendor Invoice Submission and Approval

Tags: time-management, invoicing, accounting

We have a bunch of third party vendors/contractors working for us who submit invoices back to us for payment. These invoices are a breakdown of time and fixed expenses.

In reality, it's similar to a timesheet but we cannot use a timesheeting solution here in the US as it creates legal issues for us as timesheet implies Full Time worker.

What we need is a solution which would allow our vendors to submit their invoices and time through to us, allow approval and ideally flow through to quickbooks.

The solution must be cloud based.

Any thoughts?